# Remove White Background From SlideTransition in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a requirement where I need to hide/show a widget ocassionally.

The widget is sitting right at the bottom of my layout. Immediately, the app loads I initially hide the widget by calling `_slideAnimationController?.forward();` and then I noticed the widget is hidden but a white background was left behind by the SlideTransition widget, how can I remove this white background?

I don't want my users to know that there is a widget at the bottom until it is actually necessary to display it again using the SlideTransition.

Here is my code:

```
  void initControllers() {
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollHandler);
    _slideAnimationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100));
    _slideAnimOffset = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset.zero, end: Offset(0.0, 1.0))
        .animate(_slideAnimationController!);
    _slideAnimationController?.forward();
  }

void _scrollHandler() {
if (_scrollController.position.atEdge) {
  if (_scrollController.position.pixels != 0) {
    _slideAnimationController?.reverse();
  } else {
    _slideAnimationController?.forward();
  }
}
```

}

Here is my build method:

```
      .....
         SlideTransition(
              position: _slideAnimOffset!,
              child: Container(width:100,height:100), //When the animation runs and the container is hidden, a weird white background is left off. I don't want that white background at all. Once it is hidden, it should be fully transparent.
            ),
      .....
```

And my initState is as below:

```
  @override
  initState() {
    tintSystemChrome();
    initControllers();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Any insights would be truly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem to yours.

I ended up using the `AnimatedAlign` to achieve the slide in/out animation.

Here is the sample code:

```dart
AnimatedAlign(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      heightFactor: isVisible ? 1.0 : 0.0,
      child: Container(width:100,height:100),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach would be to use `AnimatedContainer`. You can hide it by passing a height of 0:

```
 AnimatedContainer(
          height: _isHidden ? 0 : null,
          width: 100,
        )
```